# Concatenate two cell values if a condition is met

Tags: excel, if-statement, concatenation

I'm trying to see if `A1` says **black**. If it does then in `B1` I want to display **b** followed by the value in `C1`.

For example, if `C1` says **454** and `A1` says **white**, then I would like to display **w454** in `B1`.

Below is my attempt at this:

`=IF(A1="black",B1,"b"C1)-IF(A1="white",B1,"w"C1)`

Comment: Can you show a picture? If you are doing what I think you are doing, you will need VBA. (`B1` cannot equal `B1 + something` in excel without VBA). A helper column can help you do this in Excel without VBA

Comment: I'd suggest starting with a tutorial on Excel formula basics, such as [this one](https://www.lifewire.com/excel-formulas-step-by-step-tutorial-3123636).

Comment: I understood the basic formula what I did not understand was how to add in two lines of text after. but thanks for the attempted help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF you put this formula in B1, it will display what (I think) you're after:

```
=IF(A1="black","b","w")&C1
```

This assumes the value of A1 will only be black or white